Operator norm of an Idempotent operator : $\Vert P \Vert =0$ or $\Vert P \Vert \ge 1$.
I am studying Functional Analysis for the first time. Till now, I have read the concepts of Continuity of Linear Maps in NLS and will enter into the chapter of Hahn Banach Theorems. In between those topics, I got this exercise :

Let $X$ be a normed space and $P\in BL(X)$ satisfy $P^2=P$. Then $\Vert P\Vert=0$ or $\Vert P \Vert \ge1$.

Initially, I was trying to outline the proof, by using the eigenvalues of this operator, I only know that $0$ and $1$ are the eigenvalues (from my basic knowledge of Linear Algebra, I am still not aware of the behavior of this operator in the infinite-dimensional space), and for any vector $x\in X$ we can write, $P(x)=1.x$ or $P(x)=0.x$, so, by the definition of operator norm we get $$\Vert P \Vert =sup \left\{ \frac{\Vert P(x)\Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}:x\in X\right\}.$$ Using this formula, I can say for $P=0, \Vert P \Vert=0.$ But, for $P\neq0$, we have $\Vert P \Vert=1.$ But, conclusion is $\Vert P \Vert \ge 1.$ I don't know how to deal with this problem in another way. Please help me to solve this problem in a very basic way? Thank you, beforehand !!!

Look at the subset of $X$ of the form $P(x)$. Consider the set over which the supreme is taken... restrict to $P(x)$.

Hint: $|AB| \le |A| |B|$

One thing you got wrong is how "for any vector $x \in X$ one can write $Px = x$ or $Px = 0$", because this is only true iff $x \in \operatorname{ran} P$ and iff $x \in \ker P$ respectively, and while $X$ is indeed the direct sum of these two subspaces that does not mean that $Px = x$ is true for all $x \in X$.
And now you do have $\|P\| \geq 1$ and not anything more if we remove that wrong claim, by considering a fixed $x \in \operatorname{ran} P \setminus \{0\}$ to test against the definition of $\|P\|$.

yes, I made a wrong claim. I should add a counter-example for abstaining myself from making this mistake.  I will take the operator $P$ as $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \
0 \
0 \
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \
1 \
0 \
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \
1  \
0  \
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \
1 \
0 \
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 \
0  \
1  \
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \
0 \
0 \
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here, $$ P=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \
1 & 1 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 \
\end{pmatrix},  P^2=P
,$$ but we can't write $x=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \
0 \
0 \
\end{pmatrix}
$ as $P(x)=x.$
